# Laugh more, cheer up more

Tags: word-choice

When someone is always brooding and in a bad mood, is it correct if I tell him " hey, laugh more, cheer up more."
I've never heard of anyone say cheer up more, but if you can say laugh more, then can you also say cheer up more?

Comment: Cheer up means don't be sad, but that's when someone wants encouragement.  You could say look on the bright side, take it lighter, could be worse.

Comment: Some people are not happy unless they are miserable!

Comment: You might get better results by saying, "Be happy."  Better yet, tell a good joke.

Answer (score 1):

Laughing is a discrete action; saying you should do it more is essentially saying you should do it more often. This may include laughing now, but you're probably not giving the person an instruction to laugh at this very moment.

Cheering up is a change of state of mind that should be done once. Usually it's because the person is in a bad mood now.

It's not *wrong* to say someone should "cheer up more often"; maybe they're in a bad mood frequently. But it means something a little bit different than "cheer up".

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we simply say "Cheer up". Until someone has cheered up, he cannot cheer up more. As to "Laugh more," that should be "Laugh more often." We say "Cheer up" as encouragement for the moment, not as a suggestion for restructuring one's personality.